# Unable to check null for header value in request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I tried to get header value like below -

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues = request.Headers.GetValues("MyCustomerId");
var id = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
```

If header value is null or not present it is throwing error - `InvalidOperationException`

The null check for `GetValues` doesn't serve any value as it will never return null. If the header doesn't exist you will get an InvalidOperationException

Any trick to do so?

Comment: request.Headers?.GetValues("MyCustomerId");

Comment: Try catch is not a good option it will break my code i need to use it in if else

Comment: You can either use the `?` or check if `.Headers.HasKeys()` returns true.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530041/getting-a-request-headers-value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for null like so:

```
 if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["MyCustomerId"] != null)
   {
      // do something
   }
```

**Tried and tested**

Comment: the name `Request` does not exist in current context

Answer (score 4):

`request.Headers` is an instance of `System.Net.Http.HttpHeaders` (via the `HttpRequestHeaders` subclass). It has a method `TryGetValues` which can be used to safely retrieve the values of a header.

```
String header = null;
IEnumerable<String> headerValues;
if( this.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("HeaderName", out headerValues) ) {
    header = headerValues.First();
}
```

Comment: the name `Request` does not exist in current context

Comment: @Neo where is your code getting the `request` variable from? My code assumes it's in an instance method of an `ApiController` subclass.

Comment: Request variable.from.requestmessage ...ur.code.also.works.fine.thanks

Comment: HttpHeaders also has a Contains test.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Headers.Contains()` to test the existence of any headers.
See examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53502282/430742).